# issue while reading excel file with large number of cell in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to read excel file in my `CodeIgniter` application. The function `getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);` is working fine for an excel file with 14442 x 17 cells, however this function does not works for an excel file with 17590 x 17 cells. In this second case, browser ends-up with a blank page and I am not getting any error. So please tell what can be the issue?

**Code:**

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file_path);
$allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
```

Comment: try to make error reporting ON and check what's error

Answer (score 0):

Probably out of memory. It is a common issue with large excel files. 
If you only need to read the data you can use something like

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($file);
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
```

Comment: Then add error_reporting( E_ALL ); at the begining of your script. It will show all errors. Also, try to to cut your excel file, and see if your script will work fine with smaller files.